# ios Application - Manually Installation for a Custom Application

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, installation

I am currently developing an iOS application for iPhone and iPad and i need to manually install the application without the need for xcode.
Is any way to install the custom application manually like the way i do with android. For example to copy the package to the phone and install it?

The idea is to update the application after every bug fix without the need of xcode because the client does not have a mac.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question, then my answer will help you.
As your client doesn't having mac and assuming that you have created a build of app u want to install with valid distribution certificate.

1. Just upload your build here - http://www.diawi.com (You can upload provisioning profile too)

   It will give you a link. just send that link to your client and let hih/her open that link in iDevice's safari browser. Then simply hit install button to install app.
2. Use [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com).

**EDIT:** If you want to client to know update about app, then I will suggest to go for [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com) as you can mention the version and also can add comment about each build updated there and client can read it by logging in that app from it's device.

Comment: I have some problems to install the application manually using the diawi.com 

"do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at........"

I have persuaded the 'iOS Developer Program'. Do you know if it is allowed to install the application with this program type without xcode and iTunes even if my device is registered to the profile?

Answer (score 1):

Easy way, Make its .ipa file upload it on  here - http://www.diawi.com, it will give yoy url, this url give yor client and open it on safari, your application will install in client iphone without Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

They can do it via iTunes or iPhone Configuration Utility. Refer the [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-an-iPhone-Application)

Comment: I am interesting on 3d case but i don't want to use xcode to deploy the application to device.